# Maximum port range for Ubuntu

Tags: process

How many ports(as a application process) can be assigned  on Ubuntu?   How to set an application to a specific port. For example setting up bit-torrent on 3444.

Comment: As an aside, if you want to be reachable on that port from the internet, you probably need to set up port forwarding on your router.

Answer (score 7):

In general, for Linux, ports 1-1024 can only be opened by `root`. Ports 1025-65535 can be opened by anyone.

If you wanted to, you can use all 65535 ports for some purpose.